Login+endpoint Globus CLI from a server
I'm using Globus to download files from a collection of someone else (who gave me the access). I can easily download it in local in my computer. I installed Globus CLI, I logged in and I use the global transfer command with the endpoint of the collection and the endpoint I have with my Globus Personnal Connect. It works perfectly.
However I would like to do the same from a server. I can install Globus CLI easily, but I can't use global login as I have the error:

Globus CLI Error: A Globus Error Occurred.
error_type:       GlobusConnectionError
message:          ConnectionError on request`


I also tried globus login --no-local-server but I have the same error. Is there a way to log in another way ? Like in a local machine and then maybe use a session ID or something to connect to this one ?
Moreover, if I manage to connect, how will I be able to use the global transfer command as I don't have any endpoint on the server ? Is there a way to do it ?
Thanks in advance !
